# trying to run typescript with jest with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I am tying to setup jest with react having typescript .
Whenever I run `npm test` it gives errors.

npm test gives me the error below:

> Out of the box, Create React App only supports overriding these Jest
>   options:
>
> • collectCoverageFrom   • coverageReporters   • coverageThreshold
>   • snapshotSerializers.
>
> These options in your package.json Jest configuration are not
>   currently supported by Create React App:
>
> • transform   • testRegex   • moduleFileExtensions
>
> If you wish to override other Jest options, you need to eject from the
>   default setup. You can do so by running npm run eject but remember
>   that this is a one-way operation. You may also file an issue with
>   Create React App to discuss supporting more options out of the box.

I don’t want to eject, and I also want below options to work
  • transform
  • testRegex
  • moduleFileExtensions

What should I do??

my package.json file is as below

```
 {
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jest-cli": "^22.3.0",
    "jest-enzyme": "^4.2.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9009 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^3.3.13",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^3.3.13",
    "@storybook/addon-storyshots": "^3.3.13",
    "@storybook/addons": "^3.3.13",
    "@storybook/react": "^3.3.13",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.1.9",
    "@types/jest": "^22.1.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.4",
    "@types/storybook__react": "^3.0.7",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.4.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "jest": "^22.3.0",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "ts-jest": "^22.0.4",
    "ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "typescript-eslint-parser": "^13.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
`
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Have a look at [wmonk/create-react-app-typescript](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript) or the scripts therein.

Comment: The error message correctly describes the issue you are having.

Comment: me too. I did eject. but.......  Ejecting...
`config` already exists in your app folder. We cannot continue as you would lose all the changes in that file or directory. Please move or delete it (maybe make a copy for backup) and run this command again.

Answer (score 1):

[In CRA 2.1 and later versions](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/), you should be able to use TypeScript for your test files without any special jest config at all. Just be sure that your `__tests__` folder is nested underneath your `src` folder, or that your test files are inside your `src` folder and have any of the following extensions:

- `.test.js`
- `.test.ts`
- `.test.jsx`
- `.test.tsx`
- `.spec.js`
- `.spec.ts`
- `.spec.jsx`
- `.spec.tsx`

Comment: Do you *have* to name your test folder `__tests__` ?